# What is wrong with teleoanalysis (if anything)?

Tags: self-study, experiment-design, interpretation

I came across the term 'teleoanalysis' in relation to medical trials. There is no Wikipedia article on it yet, but Google search has a few links to scientific papers and their critiques.

As far as I understand, one of the main concepts of teleoanalysis is: if A causes B, and B causes C, then we can conclude that A causes C. Here is a quote from the teleoanalysis founding paper:

> *‘It may also be necessary to quantify the individual effects that relate to
>   separate steps in a causal pathway–that is, the effect of factor A on disease C
>   is determined from the estimate of the effect of A on an intermediate factor B
>   and the estimate of the effect of B on C, rather than by directly measuring the
>   effect of A on C. The exercise is like putting together the pieces in a jigsaw
>   puzzle.’*

One of the criticism mentions that this A->B->C logic is deployed when randomised trials either failed to prove relationship between A and C or are impossible to conduct, but there is some evidence of relationship between A and B  as well as B and C. The objection is that this logic is unscientific.

I was wondering if there is anything wrong with A->B->C reasoning from experiment design and general statistical science point of view?

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this concept, "teleoanalysis" today, also in the context of medical trials. I consider it fallacious.

In logic, a conditional argument is one of the form:

If A, then B.

There are four "modes" of argumentation in a conditional argument:

1: Affirming the antecedent,i.e.

A
=> B

2: Denying the consequent,

not B
=> not A

3: Denying the antecedent:

not A
=> not B

4: Affirming the consequent:

B
=> A

Modes 1 and 2 are logically valid, while modes 3 and 4 are not. This is because there may be other causes of B, e.g. D. For example, in mode 3 above, the following situation may occur.

If D, then B

not A,
D
=> B

In your example causal chain above, consider the additions of causes D and E, added as follows:

If D, then A

If E, then B

If F, then C

```
D   E   F
 \   \   \
  A-->B-->C
```

As we can see, arguing that A leads to C is fallacious, as the causes D, E and F may be involved, which are all independent of A.

There may also be a cause G, such that:

```
  G
 / \
A-->B-->C
```

and so on.
**As experiment and statistical inference are predicated on sound logic, there is no possible way for them to lend strong support for teleoanalysis.**

Its proponents may argue that by controlling for the "lurking variables" D, E and F, the causal chain A-->B-->C can be verified. However, "lurking variables" may occur at any stage of the experiment, even as a consequence of randomisation etc. and therefore are possibly unavoidable, both theoretically and practically.

Comment: John, thank you for the explanation. I was also wondering if it is in principle possible to have A => B and B => C but NOT A => C, and if there are any real life examples of that?

Comment: Dmitri, I hope I made sense - the formatting made my unclear explanation even more difficult to follow (even for me!). I cannot think of any medical examples of the scheme, A => B => C, as, in the real world, there is often no definite link between antecedent, A, and consequent, B, etc. Now, of course, in a purely formal system, teleoanalysis could be valid. For example. 
IF a number is even, then it is divisible by 2

Comment: IF a number is even (A), then it is divisible by 2 (B)
IF a number is divisible by 2 (B), then its square is even (C).
=> IF a number is even (A), then its square is even (C) 

But such necessary links between A, B and C do not exist in medicine, e.g. you could have raised blood pressure, elevated cholesterol and NOT get a heart attack etc. 
Here's a good article and post on the topic: 

http://www.bmj.com/rapid-response/2011/10/30/teleoanalysis-misleading-term

http://baddatabad.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/transitivity-bicycle-helmets-and.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. 
I guess that if a possibility can be proven, or if a single example can be found, of a case where A => B and B => C but A !=> C (i.e. NOT A => C), then the whole premise of teleoanalyisis just falls apart. 
The articles I could find of the critique of *this* particular application of teleoanalysis do not attack the concept itself, but rather stress that trails failed to prove that A => C and that is that.

I'd like to know if there is anything wrong with approach itself.

Comment: I do not doubt the transitive relation in mathematics, i.e. if A > B and B>C => A > C, but I would doubt relations apply to the very messy sphere of medical trials. I found this paper advocating for teleoanalysis: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC194099/
The authors claim that "Teleoanalysis is different from meta-analysis because it relies on combining data from different classes of evidence rather than one type of study."

Comment: As you can imagine, comparing different classes of evidence would involve subjective evaluation by the researchers as the basis of the comparison => I would be sceptical of teleoanalysis, on principle, based on such a foundation. I mean meta-anlaysis has its own issues, even within trials of a similar design - imagine the difficulty when trials are of very different qualitative nature!?